# How do I run several functions in a random order for x amount of times?

Tags: python, function

I'm creating a quiz with 10 questions and I want the following functions to run 10 times. This is my current solution, but it only runs each function once. Each function is a different question.

```
def sumchoice():
    sums = [add(), sub(), multiply()]
    for _ in range(10):
        sums
```

What I want it to do is run the functions in a random order but only ten times altogether. I've thought of using a `while` loop, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The parentheses mean you are *calling* the functions, and storing *the resulting output* in the list. Instead, try `sums = [add, sub, multiply]`, i.e. storing *the functions themselves* in the list.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Call each function 10 times, all randomly call 10 times

Comment: @Th30n at a guess, see choice 2: http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2gawvg/gcse_computing_programming_tasks_14_16_year_olds/

Comment: @jonrsharpe, oh ok, so 10 function calls in total

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling functions you store them in a list.

```
import random

def sumchoice():
    sums = [add, sub, multiply]
    for _ in range(10):
        fun = random.choice(sums) # This picks one function from sums list
        fun() # This calls the picked function
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pre-calling all the functions while creating the list. You should remove the parantheses `()` from the list and call them inside the for loop:

```
import random

def add():
    print "add"

def sub():
    print "sub"

def multiply():
    print "multiply"

sums = [add, sub, multiply]
for _ in range(10):
    random.choice(sums)()
```

Result:

```
multiply
add
multiply
sub
sub
multiply
multiply
sub
sub
sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an inbuild module called `operator` and `random`, which can be used,
The `operator` module can be used for the binary operations and `random` can be used for getting the random choice and the random number.
And there is an inbuilt function called `apply`, which can also be used.

```
>>> help(apply)


Help on built-in function apply in module __builtin__:

apply(...)
    apply(object[, args[, kwargs]]) -> value

    Call a callable object with positional arguments taken from the tuple args,
    and keyword arguments taken from the optional dictionary kwargs.
    Note that classes are callable, as are instances with a __call__() method.

    Deprecated since release 2.3. Instead, use the extended call syntax:
        function(*args, **keywords).
```

This is an alternate approach.

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, div
import random

binaryOps = (add, sub, mul, div )
#nums = ( int(raw_input('Enter number 1: ')), int(raw_input('Enter number 2: ')))
nums = (random.randint(0, 1000), random.randint(0, 1000))

def method_choice(nums):
    op = random.choice(binaryOps)
    return nums[0], nums[1], apply(op, nums)

for iteration in range(10):
    print method_choice(nums)
```